# While localisation getting Insert ' as! CVarArg' issue?

Tags: swift, swiftui, localization

I am localising my app in swiftUI.

```
let destination = "Amsterdam"
let via: LocalizedStringKey = "Paris"

Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString("homePage.string.interpolation", comment: ""), destination, via))
```

inside localisble.strings

```
"Paris" = "Parijs";
```

but getting error as [image]

is there any way to resolve this issue?

Thank you for help.

for ex.

If we use LocalizedStringKey

```
let name: LocalizedStringKey = "name"
Text(name) //inside localizabble.strings "name" = "My name";
```

Localised Result : My name

if we use string

```
let name: String = "name"
Text(name) //inside localizabble.strings "name" = "My name";
```

Localised Result (localisation fails) : name

Comment: You're passing `destination` and `via` as values to interpolate into the format string returned by `NSLocalizedString("homePage.string.interpolation", comment: "")`. In that case, why is a `via` a `LocalizedStringKey` and not just a `String`?

Comment: your question is vague as string format expect to have harcoded values

Comment: @Alexander hardcoded is just for ex.  Paris or in city name will dynamically hence its  LocalizedStringKey if i make it as string it will not localised

Comment: Just switching it from `String` to `LocalizedStringKey` won't magically localize it, from what I gather

Comment: @Alexander I have updated my question with my observation when property is with LocalizedStringKey vs with String